# Google play services in eclipse has stopped working

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

The following error occurs when I click on the imported `google-play-services_lib` in the package explorer:

```
The project description file (.project) for 'google-play-services_lib' is missing.  
This file contains important information about the project.  
The project will not function properly until this file is restored.
```

I have deleted Google Play Services from the SDK and re-installed it, but the same error occurs.

Edit: The problem has been solved. The `google-play-services_lib` folder was missing a file called `.project`

Comment: you want to add google play service lib only right

Comment: Yes, I have already added it to eclipse and it was working fine until two days ago when I updated the android SDK platform tools

Comment: k..remove the old backups from extras and add install again..

Answer (score 5):

1. select the project **google-play-services_lib** and delete it from **eclipse**, but **don't** select **delete from hard disk**
2. Select File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
3. Select Browse.... Enter /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject.

if it still not working clean project and restart eclipse

source of my answer is redo step two in [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me when I imported without "Copy files to workspace"

Answer (score 0):

What i have done. I have just copied the content of the 
`extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`
to `google_play_services\` folder.

Now clean and build `lay_service_lib` and reference again that library to your project. Clean and Build your project again and DONE..

My WorkSpace is working now with this help.